# Android landscape screen 180° rotation

Tags: android, screen-rotation

I need to know when my Android device screen is rotated from one landscape to another (rotation_90 to rotation_270).
In my Android service, I reimplemented `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` to be aware of the rotation of the device. But this method is only called by the system if the device is rotated from `ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` to `ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`, and not if it is rotated from `ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` (90°) to the other `ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` (270°) !!

How can I be called in this case?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable an OrientationEventListener to your activity.

```
OrientationEventListener mOrientationListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Orientation changed to " + orientation);

            if (orientation == OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) {
                return;
            }

            int degrees = -1;
            if (orientation < 45 || orientation > 315) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Portrait");
            } else if (orientation < 135) {
                degrees = 90;
                Log.i(TAG, "Landscape");    // This can be reverse landscape
            } else if (orientation < 225) {
                degrees = 180;
                Log.i(TAG, "Reverse Portrait");
            } else {
                degrees = 270;
                Log.i(TAG, "Reverse Landscape"); // This can be landscape
            }
        }
    };

    if (mOrientationListener.canDetectOrientation() == true) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Can detect orientation");
        mOrientationListener.enable();
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "Cannot detect orientation");
        mOrientationListener.disable();
    }
```

Comment: I could be a solution. This listener isn't to much consuming, as it is called whenever the orientation's device changed? My application is permanently active.

Comment: This is a system trigger, like you wanted. It is called whenever the angle changed. It doesn't wait until the orientation changes full 90 degrees to trigger this listener. So it is called a lot. That is the point of all those "if-else" controls.

Comment: You're right. It seems it is the only way to get this information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can save previous orientation as int member variable by using this code:

```
int oldRotation =  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
```

And then check if the device was rotated from one landscape mode to another.

```
if(rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
     int newRotation =  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
     if(newRotation != oldRotation) {
       // rotation from 90 to 270, or from 270 to 90
     }
     oldRotation = newRotation;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do that, but I'm looking for a system handler to trigger the test, or it would be necessary to regularly test the rotation state: big battery and processor consumption.